# How to stop a function with another function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function to stop looking for the next slide and also to not give me a error message that the asset is not found.

I have 6 assets in my folder.

Avoiding error:

> GET
>   file:///Users/ferfas/Desktop/1.33_1024x768/initialFrames/frame_7.jpg
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

**Code:**

```
var pictureIndex = 1;
var baseUrl = "initialFrames/";
var image_url = undefined;
var timer = setInterval(next, 2500);

var newImage = new Image();
newImage.onload = imageFound;
newImage.onerror = imageNotFound;

function next()
{
image_url = baseUrl + 'frame_' + pictureIndex + '.jpg';
tryLoadImage(image_url);
}

function tryLoadImage(url) {
newImage.src=url;
}

function imageFound() {
document.getElementById("backInit").src = image_url;
pictureIndex++;
}

function imageNotFound() {

// perform some function to stop calling next()
clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use setInterval at all?

You can load the images iteratively:

```
var pictureIndex = 1;
var baseUrl = "initialFrames/";
var image_url = undefined;

var newImage = new Image();
newImage.onload = imageFound;
newImage.onerror = imageNotFound;

function next()
{
    image_url = baseUrl + 'frame_' + pictureIndex + '.jpg';
    tryLoadImage(image_url);
}

function tryLoadImage(url) {
    newImage.src=url;
}

function imageFound() {
    document.getElementById("backInit").src = image_url;
    pictureIndex++;
    //you can check here if the pictureIndex image exists, and then only call next if it exists
    // if (imageExists()) {
    next();
    // }
}

function imageNotFound() {
    console.log('done loading images...');
} 

next();
```